# Overheating laptop: assign lm-sensor output to hardware component

Tags: temperature, lm-sensors

### short:

How can I find out which entry of lm-sensors corresponds to which hardware component for my HP EliteBook 8540w, with [Intel 5 series chipsest](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/chipsets/5-chipset-3400-chipset-datasheet.html)?

### the story:

I have a laptop (HP EliteBook 8540w, with [Intel 5 series chipsest](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/chipsets/5-chipset-3400-chipset-datasheet.html)) that keeps overheating.

It is quite old already, so I did open it up and replaced all the dried thermal grease / pads with new grease. It did help, but looks like I missed one component.

Here is the output of lm-sensors during idle for some time (with open firefox)

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +68.0°C  (crit = +127.0°C)
temp2:         +0.0°C  (crit = +127.0°C)
temp3:        +37.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp4:        +57.0°C  (crit = +127.0°C)
temp5:        +77.0°C  (crit = +115.0°C)
temp6:        +20.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp7:        +69.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)                                   
temp8:        +68.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)                                   
temp9:         +0.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)                                   
temp10:       +88.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)                                   
                                                                           
coretemp-isa-0000                                                          
Adapter: ISA adapter                                                       
Core 0:       +68.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)                   
Core 1:       +68.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)                   
Core 2:       +68.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)                   
Core 3:       +68.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

For me, it looks like, the component reporting as temp10 could be the problem. **How to find out what actual hardware component is reporting as temp10?** (The laptop usually overheats and shuts down during computational desktop load, no gpu load involved)
I tried reading the manual of the chipset (above, section 22.2, p868, Thermal sensor registers) but I didn't get a clue. [Here](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/7607/how-to-identify-lm_sensors-output/) is a similar list for a thinkpad. I'm looking for something like this.

Note: I'm not asking for help with my cooling problems (But of course, tipps as comments are welcome.)

Comment: Overheating that increases with a laptop's age, is more likely to be caused by dust and grunge blocking the air cooling path, in some hidden twisty corner or cooling grill. You didn't mention cleaning them.

Comment: ah sorry, I thought it was obvious that I cleaned them when I took apart the whole thing to replace the thermal grease ;) Thanks never the less for the advise!

Comment: Is there anything useful in `/etc/sensors3.conf`?

Comment: It looks like that model should have a Quadro GPU? If it does my money is on that being the device. If you have any GPU monitoring utils they should be able to pinpoint its sensors only. It doesnt matter if the GPU isnt being used as laptops used shared coolers so an increase in temperature in one reduces the cooling capacity for the other.